# how to get attribute of input in asp.net forms

Tags: asp.net

I have an input in ASP.NET form. I did not use ASP.NET controls, but the adjective `runat="server"` was used. Like this:

```
<input id="cmbIOType" name="cmbIOType" runat="server" list="listcmbIOType" autocomplete="off" data-id="564" value="111" />
```

I'm using `strig valcmbIOType = cmbIOType.value;` to get the input value. I also need to `data-id` the input.
I used `string idcmbIOType = cmbIOType.Attributes["data-id"]` but returned NULL.
Meanwhile, the `data-id` is made by Jquery.

Please help.

Comment: What does this have to do with MVC?

Comment: Post code where you data-id is made by jquery.

Comment: No other attributes than `name` and `value` are posted. Take a different approach, for example using AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this:

```
<input id="cmbLoc" name="cmbLoc" runat="server" list="listcmbLoc" autocomplete="off" />
<datalist id="listcmbLoc">
       <option data-id="15" value="CPF"></option>
       <option data-id="18" value="HOLD"></option>
       <option data-id="19" value="CCR"></option>
 </datalist>
<div style="display: none"><input id="cmbLoc_ID" type="text" name="cmbLoc_ID" runat="server"/></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#cmbLoc").change(function () {
$("#MainContent_cmbLoc_ID").val($('#listcmbLoc').find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]').data('id'));
          });
    });
</script>
```

And enter `cmbLoc_ID.value` in the code behind it to get `data-id`.